# FTP in java - ftp url has dollar sign

Tags: java, ftp

I am trying to upload a file via ftp

My problem is that the ftp url, lets say X, I actually need to access a directory within in
which is of this format $Y.Z

I am unsure how to do this in Java

I have tried this:

```
boolean success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(host + "$Y.Z");
```

and

```
boolean success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(host + "\$Y.Z");
```

and

```
boolean success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("$Y.Z");
```

and

```
boolean success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("\$Y.Z");
```

and they have all failed (success = false)

can someone help me please?

Comment: dollar sign should not be a problem in your URL.i assume the problem is something different.Does this Directory really exists?Maybe your FTP-Library can show some more output? Like **WHY** does the dir change not work (access denied?, folder does not exists?)

Comment: There is no "in java" about this. What is this "ftpClient" class you're using? Apache commons-net? Have you checked its API documentation?